# How do I split file removals into a separate changeset in git

Tags: git

I have a massive git changeset on a local branch. It contains file additions, file modifications and file deletions.

How do I split the file deletions into a separate subsequent changeset? (To make the additions and modifications easier to review.)

(In case it matters, this is git-cinnabar, not plain git.)

Comment: How are you going to review the changeset? If you are using `git diff` you can take advantage of its `--diff-filter` option and suppress the deleted files.

Comment: It's most likely going to be reviewed using Mozilla's ReviewBoard Web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that all your changes are currently unstaged, you can use the powerful `ls-files` utility:

```
git ls-files --deleted | xargs git add
```

Note this assumes that cinnabar doesn't mask this `git` feature, and that you are using a `bash`-like shell.

Comment: Thank you. So far, this seems closest to what I'm looking for. Since the changes are already part of a changeset (in order to be able to rebase the branch), I guess next I'll need to find out how to uncommit the changeset.

Comment: You can uncommit a git commit with `git reset` if it's the latest commit. But if it's a few commits back, you can use `git rebase -i` checkout the git docs on "rewriting history" https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History

Comment: Thanks. git reset HEAD^ followed by the answer with xargs added worked. (I edited xargs into the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use partial add

instead of ding a simple `git add .` add the `-p` flag and you will see the option `s` to split the big changes into a smaller one.

If the change is not enough for you you can split it even more with the `e` edit mode.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems to require manual action for each change instead of programmatically identifying the whole-file deletions and moving those into a separate changeset.

Answer (score 0):

All of this assumes that the changes are uncommitted, unstaged, and simply in your work tree.  If that is not the case comment with the current state of things and I can update with revised procedures (which will boil down to getting back to the previous commit if need be, unstaging any changes, ...).

When you say "file deletions", I take that to mean you completely removed some files and want to separate that from files you updated (as opposed to wanting to separate deleted lines from added/updated lines within a single file).

If that's the case, you can pick and choose which files you `add` without having to use `git add -p`.  (The `-p` puts you in the "patch" submenu of "interactive mode", where you can pick individual line changes to stage or unstage; it's probably overkill here.)

So all you really would need is to supply the filenames of the deleted files when you do your `git add`.

```
git clone someRepo
rm file1
touch file2
vi file3
rm someDir/file4
git add file1
git add someDir/file4
git commit -mDeletions
git add .
git commit -m"Changes And Additions"
```

If a bunch of deletions are in `someDirectory`, and there are no additions or edits in `someDirectory`, then you can `git add someDirectory` to stage all of them.  If this would catch one or two additions, you can stage the directory then use `git reset HEAD -- someDirectory/addedFile` to unstage the file you didn't want.

If the files are scattered throughout the work tree alongside changes you don't want to stage, use something based on `git status |grep deleted` to get the filenames for the first commit and feed them to a script to stage them.

Or an interactive add certainly can do the job

```
git add -i
```

but as long as you're picking *files* and not *individual changes within a file*, you don't need the patch mode.

Comment: Thanks, but not having to manually enumerate the deleted files was the goal. That is, I'm looking for a way to automatically identify the whole-file deletions and move them to a separate changeset.

Comment: A point I addressed if you read the whole answer. Lucky for you, someone else knew an even better way to get the deletion list.

Answer (score 0):

You can undo file deletions performed in your branch as follows (the files will be restored to the state corresponding to the commit from which your branch was started):

```
# Set these bash variables to the correct values
upstream=master
branch=dev

git checkout "$branch"
deleted_files="$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D "${upstream}...$branch")"

# Split the list of deleted files into individual filenames
# It is assumed that the filenames don't contain newline characters!!!
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a deleted_files_array <<<"$deleted_files"

git reset $(git merge-base "$upstream" "$branch") -- "${deleted_files_array[@]}"
git commit -m "restored deleted files"
```

> **Caveat**:
>
> Above procedure will not work if the filenames of your
>   deleted files contain newline characters.